# Optimal way to copy mass data between two SQL Server 2008 tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, copy, large-data

I have two identical databases in my local network: `DB1` on the main server and `DB2` on another machine. The two databases have the same structure (`DB2` is restored from `DB1`).

I need to copy (using vb6) data from `DB1` tables to `DB2` on demand (not in real time). Some tables in `DB1` contain more than 2'000'000 rows.

I can't use merge replication, mirroring or log shipping technologies.

I tried to create a linked server and I used

```
insert into [local-table] 
    select from [linked-server]
```

It works but not for big tables. I got the error message of request expiration (I use `connexion.commandTimeout = 0`).

My question: is there a method to copy a large amount of data between two SQL Servers?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it with OPENQUERY?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
SELECT a, b, c, ...
FROM OPENQUERY([Servername],
'SELECT a, b, c, ... FROM [OriginalDB].[dbo].Tablename()')
```